# Rabbi Akiva seeing Bar Kochba sleeping on his back?

Tags: midrash, sleep, rabbi-akiva-ben-yosef, story-identification, bar-kochba

I once saw it in some sefer that Rabbi Akiva saw Bar Kochba sleeping on his back (not on his side) and then he knew that he wasn't Mashiach. Does anyone know where this is written? I'm pretty sure its not in the Talmud.

Comment: I heard this about a later rabbi and shabtai tzvi

Comment: @BabySeal remember who or where you heard this?

Comment: I think from Rabbi Naftali Elfenbein of Yeshivat Mercaz Hatorah in Talpiot, Jerusalem.

Comment: The story is told about the Taz, who sent emissaries to evaluate Shabtai Tzvi. The problem with story, is that SZ had much worse things that could be said about him, beyond not being meticulous about sleeping while lying on his back...

Comment: There was a progression to Shabtai Tzvi. The lying on his back was how he realized ST was a fraud early on, before he went totally off the deep end.

Comment: @IsraelReader it's not the sz we care to say that about , it's the potential mashiach we care to say that about -